# Build MonoGame project on VSTS

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, azure-devops

I've problem with building my MonoGame project in Visual Studio Team Services. An error is thrown when the solution is built. I've searched a lot but I haven't found any solution. Here is the error:

```
ESA\ESA.csproj(138,11): Error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
```

I have MonoGame nugget package imported but it always doesn't works. Here is <import> tag from **.csproject** file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" />
```

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: Hi Zdeněk! Can you confirm whether or not `msbuild.exe.Config` exists in the folder that it's looking in?

Comment: @TJWolschon do you mean this folder (`$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets`)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets` in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\

Comment: This file is probably there but I can't read it because is located on the remote MS servers.

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent? The hosted agent probably won't work for this because it requires additional software to be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a private build agent on the machine that has MonoGame installed, then build the project with that build agent.

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows?view=vsts)

On the other hand, based on this thread ([Can't create a Continuous Integration environment due to installer issues](https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/5171)), you can use NuGet package, with this way you need to modify project file to change the Import path `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" />` to the actual package path.

You can add msbuild conditions so that locally you use the installation and no the build server you use Nuget.[MSBuild Conditions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx)

For example:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets')" />
<Import Project="{actual package path}\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" Condition="!Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets')" />
```

Comment: Could you, please, review the writing of your answer? I think the punctuation and the wording is incorrect and makes it difficult to understand it.